# C++ and Matlab combination

Tags: c++, matlab

I am writing a simulation of some differential equation. My idea was the following:

```
1. Write the core simulation (moving forward in time, takes a lot of time) in C++
2. Do initialisation and the analysis of the results with a program
   like Matlab/Scilab
```

The reason for (1) is that C++ is faster if implemented correctly.

The reason for (2)  is that for me it is easier to make analysis, like plotting etc..., with a program like Matlab.

Is it possible to do it like this, how do I call C++ from Matlab? 
Or do you have some suggestions to do it in a different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Matlab has a C/C++ [API](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/programming-interfaces-for-c-c-fortran-com.html).

This API permits to:

- Write C++ functions which can be invoked from Matlab
- Read/Write data from a `.mat` file
- Invoke the Matlab engine from C++

I am working to something similar to what you are trying to do, my approach is:

- Import in C++ the input data from a `.mat` file
- Run the simulation
- Export the results back in a `.mat` file

The Matlab API is in C, and I suggest you to write a C++ wrapper for your convenience.

In order to work with Matlab `mxArray`, I suggest to take a look at the [`boost::multi_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html) library.

In particular you can initialize an object of type `multi_array_ref` from a Matlab `mxArray` like this:

```
boost::multi_array_ref<double,2> vec ( mxGetPr (p), boost::extents[10][10], boost::fortran_storage_order() );
```

This approach made the code much more readable.

Answer (score 4):

You could certainly do as you suggest.  But I suggest instead that you start by developing your entire solution in Matlab and only then, if its performance is genuinely holding your work back, consider translating key elements into C++. This will optimise the use of your time, possibly at the cost of your computer's time.  But a computer is a modern donkey without a humane society to intervene when you flog it to death.

As you suggest, well written C++ can be expected to be faster than interpreted Matlab.  But ask yourself *What is Matlab written in ?*  For much of its computationally-intensive core functionality Matlab calls libraries written in C++ (or whatever).  Your task would be not to write code faster than interpreted Matlab, but faster than C++ (or whatever) written by specialists urged on by a huge market of installed software.

Comment: I've already written the part, where I move forward in time, in c++. It takes about 30 seconds for a short simulation, but can take a lot more. I didn't try this in Matlab, but as it includes some big for loops, it should take a lot more time in Matlab, shouldn't it?

Comment: Test and measure.  Arguments about performance are settled by data, not by discussion. But if you have already written the C++ sure, why not just build it into a MEX file and wrap it in Matlabby goodness for ease of use and ease of visualisation. As always, there is extensive documentation to teach you how to call C++ routines from Matlab. I'm certainly not going to try to compete with the Mathworks on that front.

Comment: And your question is now revealed to be somewhat misleading since you now admit that you already have a C++ version of the computationally-intensive part of your simulation program.  So don't be surprised if the answers you get are somewhat off target.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I wanted to know if there is a better way for future projects. 'MEX file' was the keyword I was looking for.

Comment: @Thomas use matlab's `profile` to find the bottlenecks of your code - then you can implement them as C++ mex-files.

Answer (score 1):

You can call your own C, C++, or Fortran subroutines from the MATLAB command line as if they were built-in functions. These programs, called binary MEX-files, are dynamically-linked subroutines that the MATLAB interpreter loads and executes.
You should set compiler, look here [Setting up mex to use the Visual Studio 2010 compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078094/setting-up-mex-to-use-the-visual-studio-2010-compiler).
All about MEX-files here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-mex-files-to-call-c-c-and-fortran-programs.html.